# Run batch of nohup scripts consecutively

Tags: bash, asynchronous, nohup

I have a collection of "parent" python scripts `script_1.py`, ... ,`script_n.py`, each of which launches a bunch of different "child" python scripts asynchronously using os.system and nohup. Each parent script also saves the the PIDs of its children to `/tmp/task_1/kill.sh`,..., `/tmp/task_n/kill.sh`

I want to run all *n* parent scripts consecutively, ensuring that all the asynchronous children of parent *i-1* have completed executing before running parent *i*.

My attempt (for two parents) was to run a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

python script_1.py &
wait
python script_2.py &
```

However, this launches all children of `script_1.py` and `script_2.py` according to `ps -ef | grep python`.

FYI: The contents of each kill.sh files is of the form

```
#!/bin/sh
kill 36713
kill 36715
etc..
```

Comment: if you want to run the python scripts *consecutively*, then don't background them!?

Comment: @JeffSchaller : even if I run script_1.py and script_2.py as foreground processes, there is no guarantee that the children of script_1 have finished executing by the time `python script_2.py` gets called. how can I ensure my desired behavior?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I suspect that I need to use the list of PIDs generated by script_1 to decide when to launch script_2 but I'm not sure how to do this. Am I overthinking this?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to run the corresponding kill scripts?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I want the child scripts to finish executing on their own. After which, the next parent script should begin. The kill scripts are simply a tool to allow early termination.

Comment: Seems like parent #1, run in the foreground, will naturally wait for its children to exit, at which point you can continue with parent #2...

Comment: @JeffSchaller parent #1's children are launched as background asynchronous processes using nohup so they will continue to run long after script_1.py has finished executing. I checked this behavior using `ps -ef | grep python`

Comment: i do think you are over thinking this:
what you really want to do is use threading to run your scripts, so they can run in parallel, and then join in the end. Otherwise you need to record each PID, check in a loop that each child process is still running, and only when no child process is left running you can terminate your parent process.
seems way more complicated than threading

Answer (score 0):

You want to wait for all childs still running after the first wait is finished.
When the main script is finished, I assume the file /tmp/task_1/kill.sh is complete. You can find the pid's with
sed -n '/kill/ s/kill //p' /tmp/task_1/kill.sh
You want to wait for these:

```
#!/bin/bash
python script_1.py &
wait
wait $(sed -n '/kill/ s/kill //p' /tmp/task_1/kill.sh)
python script_2.py &
```

You can also test in a loop:

```
scriptnr=1
while test -x "script_${scriptnr}.py"; do
   python script_${scriptnr}.py &
   wait
   wait $(sed -n '/kill/ s/kill //p' /tmp/task_${scriptnr}/kill.sh)
   ((scriptnr++))
done
```